# Point center in ufrd model and move_base package

Tags: ros, navigation, urdf, footprint, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all!
I am would like create my own urdf model. It will be robot with differential drive like in the Pi robot.
But I have a questions:

What will be center of robot? point rotate or geometry center of robot in URDF model? regarding what point set all sensors?

How I can set this model in costmap_common_params file in move_base package? footprint: [[-0.2,-0.2],[-0.2,0.2], [0.2, 0.2], [0.2,-0.2]]  or robot_radius: 0.21?

[image description http://www.pirobot.org/blog/0024/base_level_0.jpg](http://www.pirobot.org/blog/0024/base_level_0.jpg)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/122401/point-center-in-ufrd-model-and-move_base-package./) by [seredin](https://answers.ros.org/users/8936/seredin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2014-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For a diff drive robot, the typical place for a base_link frame location would be centered between the two wheels (and often projected onto the ground plane, but that's less important). If your wheels are centered on the robot (like a turtlebot) then a robot radius makes sense. If your wheels are offset from the center (like pirobot) then the footprint might be a better option.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1